# Using SQL Server trigger to change format of text

Tags: sql, sql-server

What I'm trying to do is when new data is entered into the db, a trigger is run that converts all text to TitleCase. How I previously did this was to create a function, then using `UPDATE TABLE` to call that function, but this is very labour intensive.

My previous SQL function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[InitCap]
     (@InputString varchar(4000)) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(4000)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Index          INT
    DECLARE @Char           CHAR(1)
    DECLARE @PrevChar       CHAR(1)
    DECLARE @OutputString   VARCHAR(255)

    SET @OutputString = LOWER(@InputString)
    SET @Index = 1

    WHILE @Index <= LEN(@InputString)
    BEGIN
        SET @Char     = SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Index, 1)
        SET @PrevChar = CASE WHEN @Index = 1 THEN ' '
                             ELSE SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Index - 1, 1)
                        END

        IF @PrevChar IN (' ', ';', ':', '!', '?', ',', '.', '_', '-', '/', '&', '''', '(')
        BEGIN
            IF @PrevChar != '''' OR UPPER(@Char) != 'S'
               SET @OutputString = STUFF(@OutputString, @Index, 1, UPPER(@Char))
        END

        SET @Index = @Index + 1
    END

    RETURN @OutputString
END
```

How the function was called:

```
update dbo.table
set colName = [dbo].[InitCap](colName);
```

New trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TableInsert]
ON [Table] 
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @InputString varchar(4000) 
    DECLARE @Index          INT
    DECLARE @Char           CHAR(1)
    DECLARE @PrevChar       CHAR(1)
    DECLARE @OutputString   VARCHAR(255)

    SET @OutputString = LOWER(@InputString)
    SET @Index = 1

    WHILE @Index <= LEN(@InputString)
    BEGIN
        SET @Char     = SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Index, 1)
        SET @PrevChar = CASE WHEN @Index = 1 THEN ' '
                            ELSE SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Index - 1, 1)
                        END

        IF @PrevChar IN (' ', ';', ':', '!', '?', ',', '.', '_', '-', '/', '&', '''', '(')
        BEGIN
             IF @PrevChar != '''' OR UPPER(@Char) != 'S'
                SET @OutputString = STUFF(@OutputString, @Index, 1, UPPER(@Char))
        END

        SET @Index = @Index + 1
    END

    RETURN @OutputString
END
```

Is this the correct way? What could I use to instead of `@InputString`?

Thanks

Comment: you cannot use @inputstring: it could happen that many rows are updated at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would actually advise keeping your `InitCap` function, since it's nice to have that logic tucked away for re-use; there's no point in having that logic in more than one place. With that in mind, your trigger really doesn't do much except update the value that got inserted:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TableInsert]
ON [Table] 
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE 
        t
    SET 
        t.colName = dbo.InitCap(i.colName)
    FROM 
        dbo.table t
    INNER JOIN 
        inserted i
        ON
        i.primaryKeyColumn = t.primaryKeyColumn
END
```

Comment: @Cory , Thanks for your comment, could you explain to be what your triiger is doing? thanks

Comment: `inserted` is a "table" available to you in the trigger that contains the values that were inserted. You are modifying the column that contains the input string `i.colName`, and then the `UPDATE` joins your original table to the `inserted` one to determine which row to update. You need this construct in case many rows were updated at the same time (`inserted` can contain more than one record).

Comment: Im getting an error : `Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.InitCap" or the name is ambigous` why could this be?

Comment: Are you still having that issue -- just want to make sure since you marked this as the accepted answer.

Comment: Yes, I am still have that issue

Comment: Is your function defined in a different database?

Comment: No it works now ,I was referencing a view not a table , Thanks for your help. is there anyway I could get it to run on a view?

Comment: No, triggers only work on tables. Views are for an entirely different purpose, usually, and you wouldn't want to be away from the underlying tables anyway. Best to keep the trigger as close to the raw data as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the MS-specific syntax is for this, but a BEFORE INSERT FOR EACH ROW trigger gives you access to the new data in a record named NEW and allows you to manipulate the record's contents (eg. changing the case of values) before the INSERT is actually performed.

Comment: SQL Server does not have a BEFORE trigger. It has INSTEAD OF and AFTER triggers.

Comment: I was not aware of that. Insert gratuitous Microsoft slam here.

Comment: They just implement triggers a little differently than some other vendors. All DBMS have some interesting ways of working with triggers. You can achieve your idea using an INSTEAD of trigger. They also fire once per operation instead once per row like some other DBMS out there.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TableInsert]
ON [Table] 
AFTER INSERT
AS
UPDATE tbl
SET tbl.colName=[dbo].[InitCap](ins.colName)
FROM [table] tbl INNER JOIN inserted ins ON ....--your keys;
```